# trigger the typeahead event programmatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap and working with typeaheads. I can set type aheads for an input field using:

```
var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
$('#search-field').typeahead({source: subjects});
```

But this is static. I want to provide autosuggest feature and thus as user types a character/word, I fetch the query typed by user and make an http request to fetch the suggestion in JSON format. Following is my code to do this:

```
$('#search-field').on('keyup', function(){
// fetch the search query
var query = $(this).val();
// array containing suggestions
var suggestions=[];

$.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest/?q='+ query +'&wt=json&json.wrf=?', {

})
    .done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion, function(){
            // add the suggestions into the array
            suggestions.push(this);
        });

        // set the source for typeahead
        $('#search-field').typeahead({source: suggestions});
        // how to trigger the search field to show these suggestions now???
    });
```

So as you can see, I fetch suggestions, create an array and set the source of typeahead. But the suggestions won't be shown because for that something has to be entered and doing that will again call my 'keyup' event handler :(! So is there a way to solve this issue and show the typeaheads as soon as source is registered for it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested feature is already built into the typeahead library, it allows the source to be a function as given the the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) as given below

```
$('#search-field').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest/?q='+ query +'&wt=json&json.wrf=?', {

        }).done(function(response){
            var suggestions=[];
            $.each(response.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion, function(){
                // add the suggestions into the array
                suggestions.push(this);
            });

            process(suggestions)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I will be thankful if you will provide me a link to the documentation for this so that I can explore more options with this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @stalin, it is a callback method passed to the source function which has to be called with the dynamic source array

Comment: @stalin I already have added the link to the documentation in my answer. you can find it again [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) under the options section read about all the available options

Comment: @stalin you can remove the keyup handler