# How can I use Twitter Typeahead with SignalR to get autocomplete suggestions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, twitter-typeahead

The client-side javascript below doesn't work, as the code completes before cb gets populated. Populating cb in the SignalR *done* function fails as it is too late because the call is asynchronous.

How can I populate *source* using SignalR in response to user input into my typeahead textbox?

```
    var tonameSource = function (query, cb) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            var prefix = $('#toname').val();
            var myCBval = [];
            talk.server.getpcont(prefix, ConnectionId)
                    .done(function (mmID) {
                        $.each(mmID, function () {
                            var myOBJ = this;
                            myCBval.push({
                                name: myOBJ.name,
                                ID: myOBJ.ID
                            });
                        });
                    }).fail(function (error) {
                        //
                    });              

            cb(myCBval);

        }, 300)
    };

    $(".tt-toname").typeahead(null, {
        minLength: 2,
        source: tonameSource,
        displayKey: 'name',
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        //$(".tt-name").typeahead('val', datum.name).typeahead('close');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happily I found [trigger the typeahead event programmatically using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521993/trigger-the-typeahead-event-programmatically-using-jquery/17522048#17522048) which gave me the answer by analogy. So SignalR can populate the Twitter Typeahead suggestions.

The answer in my case was in setting *source* as you see below. From that I learned that calling the callback function can - and must - be done only inside of the *done* or *fail* segments which are run when the call to the SignalR server does its async return. And it is the callback method that produces the display of the suggestions.

```
    <div class="typeahead-wrapper">
       <input class="tt-toname" id="toname" name="toname" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
    </div>
```

(Recommend skip to update following this section!)

```
    $(".tt-toname").typeahead(null, {
        minLength: 2,    

        // begin source      
        source: function (query, process) {
            var prefix = $('#toname').val();
            var myCBval = [];// my callback value

            // "talk" is = $.connection.talkHub; and set elsewhere globally
            //getpcont is a custom SignalR method that is on the server
            talk.server.getpcont(prefix, ConnectionId) 
                    .done(function (mmID) {
                        $.each(mmID, function () {
                            var myOBJ = this;
                            myCBval.push({
                                name: myOBJ.name,
                                ID: myOBJ.ID
                            });
                            process(myCBval);//process is a callback method
                        });
                    }).fail(function (error) {
                        process([]);//process is a callback method, don't know if this is necessary here, but will produce no suggestions
                    });
        }
        // end source

        ,
        displayKey: 'name',
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        //$(".tt-name").typeahead('val', datum.name).typeahead('close');
    });
```

UPDATED Sept 11, 2015 to work with typeahead.js version 0.11.1 ------------------------

```
  $(".tt-toname").typeahead({
       // hint: true,
        //highlight: true,
        minLength: 2           
    }
        ,
        {
            name: 'myname',
            limit:10,
            source: function (q, sync, async) {

                talk.server.getcontacts(q, ConnectionId)
                        .done(function (data, status)
                        {
                            async(data);
                        }
                        ).fail(function (error) {
                            alert("in fail" + error);
                        });

            },
            displayKey: 'name'
        });
```

Also see: [Bootstrap Typeahead not showing hints as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007825/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-hints-as-expected)